# php mail not sending "invalid email address"

Tags: php, email

im getting the "invalid email address"

all is hardcoded for testing, what is missing? thanks!

```
<html>
<head><title>PHP Mail Sender</title></head>
<body>
<?php

/* All form fields are automatically passed to the PHP script through the array $HTTP_POST_VARS. */
$email = $HTTP_POST_VARS['example@example.com'];
$subject = $HTTP_POST_VARS['subjectaaa'];
$message = $HTTP_POST_VARS['messageeeee'];

/* PHP form validation: the script checks that the Email field contains a valid email address and the Subject field isn't empty. preg_match performs a regular expression match. It's a very powerful PHP function to validate form fields and other strings - see PHP manual for details. */

if (!preg_match("/\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/", $email)) {
  echo "<h4>Invalid email address</h4>";
  echo "<a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Back</a>";
} elseif ($subject == "") {
  echo "<h4>No subject</h4>";
  echo "<a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Back</a>";
}

/* Sends the mail and outputs the "Thank you" string if the mail is successfully sent, or the error string otherwise. */
elseif (mail($email,$subject,$message)) {
  echo "<h4>Thank you for sending email</h4>";
} else {
  echo "<h4>Can't send email to $email</h4>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with php not sending mail.. you're using a bad regex to validate email addresses. Your code never gets anywhere close to actually calling `mail()` because you never let it. You should be using `filter_var` with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL instead of rolling your own broken system.

Comment: If you've just written this PHP code and you're still learning, please go an find yourself a more up-to-date tutorial than the one you've been using -- you're using some **badly** out of date techniques here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$email = $HTTP_POST_VARS['jaaanman2324@gmail.com'];
$subject = $HTTP_POST_VARS['subjectaaa'];
$message = $HTTP_POST_VARS['messageeeee'];
```

to

```
$email ='jaaanman2324@gmail.com';
$subject ='subjectaaa';
$message = 'messageeeee';
```

Comment: because `$HTTP_POST_VARS['jaaanman2324@gmail.com'];` doesn't exist. You need to pass form var inside this., instead you have added the value.

Comment: Say if your `form` had an input field `<input type='text' name='email'>` then here you should access it like `$HTTP_POST_VARS['email'];` which would then work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want it to be hardcoded like this:

```
$email = 'jaaanman2324@gmail.com';
```

Otherwise you are trying to get the value out of HTTP_POST_VARS with the key of `jaaanman2324@gmail.com`

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use `$HTTP_POST_VARS`, it's `$_POST` now.

Second, by writing `$HTTP_POST_VARS['jaaanman2324@gmail.com']` you're looking for table element with `juanman234@gmail.com` key.
That's not what you wanted to do.

If you want to hardcode it, write

```
$email = 'jaaanman2324@gmail.com';`
```

if not, write

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

to get `email` field from form.